# Connection error in bitvise ssh client

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, putty, openshift-online-2

Iam able to connect to ssh server host on openshift using putty but while using the same setting in bitvise ssh client i get the folowing error -

01:47:18.424    Connecton failed. getaddrinfo() failed. Windows error 11003: A
                non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.
01:47:18.424    The SSH2 session has been terminated.

I have added the public key in it keypair section. 
is there a way to connect to ssh servers on port 22 using bitvise.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by following these instructions:

- generate your ssh keys
- add key to openshift, if not done already
- import the key into the user keypair manager (private key)
- import the key into the host key manager (public key)

  - for host, grab the remote access url and remove the ssh. *everything is needed except the ssh for the url and save
  - add everything after the @ to the host back on the main application and everything before the @ to the username field
  - select the slot for the key you imported and enter the passphrase
  - when / if you get prompted to accept a cert, accept it

you should now be connected with ssh and sftp!

[image]

Comment: i did exactly the same but still error is coming
"The SSH2 session has terminated with error. Reason: FlowSocketReader: Error receiving bytes. Windows error 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host "

Comment: can you please tell me the steps you took? I can connect on port 22 without issue. Error receiving bytes may possible be a firewall issue in windows or your router.. Maybe even a screenshot would help better, naturally with identifiable information blacked out...

Comment: yeah sure,
as u said earlier i have added public key to Host key manager and private key to Client key manager in options tab i have selected open terminal option also . here is the screenshot [link](http://s13.postimg.org/svkkz9dnb/Capture.png)        im able to connect via putty though .

Comment: u might need to connect to the vpn. when forgetting to tunnel with the remote host i have had this error "The SSH2 session has terminated with error. Reason: FlowSocketReader: Error receiving bytes. Windows error 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host "

Comment: so to ssh to openshift i need to connect to vpn first ?