# SSH connection strange behavior

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am using windows10 and I can connect to my server(Ubuntu 18.04) with PowerShell and Putty.
but not with the other two ssh client I have (MobaXtrem,Bitvise).
but when i turn on my VPN(SeedVpn) on client, I can connect with this two apps as well.

i wonder if this is a (Network,Firewall,Server) problem why Powershell and Putty working ?
and if this is a problem with that two apps why with VPN i can connect?
(also SFTP connection works on this two apps without VPN)

I did not set any rules on Server and I use Server IP as hostname not domain.

P.S. English is not my first language,sorry if there are grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Your ssh clients must be configured differently, but we can't tell unless you show us their configuration.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Thanks! I'm using default configs and even import Putty session to  MobaXtrem but didn't worked. 
At this point I did what this [topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/710870/connection-error-in-bitvise-ssh-client) did but not helped.
in this topic @Matoeil says `u might need to connect to the vpn first` but why? i don't want connect to a VPN for ssh connection.